# Inheritence of the move assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, move-assignment-operator

I require some help in understanding the process of inheritance of move assignment operator. 
For a given base class

```
class Base
{
public:
    /* Constructors and other utilities */
    /* ... */

    /* Default move assignment operator: */
    Base &operator=(Base &&) = default;
    /* One can use this definition, as well: */
    Base &operator=(Base &&rhs) {std::move(rhs); return *this;}

    /* Data members in Base */
    /* ... */
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    /* Constructors that include inheritance and other utilities */
    /* ... */

    Derived &operator=(Derived &&rhs);

    /* Additional data members in Derived */
    /* ... */
};
```

I am not quite sure how to invoke base move assignment operator inside the derived class? Should I just use scope operator and say

```
Base::std:move(rhs);
```

followed by the subsequent `std::move(...)` of the additional items defined in `Derived` class, or is there some other method?

Comment: Your hand written definition is illustrative? As written `{std::move(rhs); return *this;}` doesn't move anything

Comment: Yes, std::move(rhs) is an abbreviation for item_i=std::move(rhs.item_i), where i goes over all data members in Base class. I apologize if I did not make that clear.

Comment: *std::move(rhs) is an abbreviation* Please don't use abbreviations like this. Sincerely, the world.

Comment: `static_cast<Base&>(*this) = std::move(rhs);`

Answer (score 8):

To invoke inherited `operator=`, you normally invoke inherited `operator=`.

```
Derived &operator=(Derived &&rhs) {
   Base::operator=(std::move(rhs));
   // do the derived part
   return *this;
}
```

It doesn't matter if it's a copy assignment, a move assignment, or some kind of user-defined assignment, the pattern is the same.